# Add fade and press outside div to reset to Jquery hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this perfectly working jquery script to hide and show content on button press. I would like to worked further on this and add so that the content have a little fade so it looks smoother. I would also like so that if i would press outside any of the buttons it would return to the default content. I've tried adding some transition fades via css but did not get it working. All help appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Put all the images in a JavaScript array
var $imgs = $(".section-link");

// If you store your content in an array of objects, you can do this without creating
// more than one display div. You'll just get the content from the object in the
// array that has the same index as the image (within a different array)
var data = [
  {
    title: "Fair trade",
    text: "The Process from start is fair to all who are included in making our clothes."
  },
  {
    title: "Toxicfree",
    text: "Our clothes does not contain any toxic materials and are made under toxicfree conditions."
  },
  {
    title: "Quality",
    text: "Our clothes have sustainable and high quality."
  },
  {
    title: "Organic",
    text: "All the materials and processes are fully organic and friendly to our planet."
  },
  {
    title: "Vegan",
    text: "We care about the animals, all clothes are crueltyfree and vegan."
  },
];

// Get reference to the output area
var $outputDiv = $(".section-display");

// Set a click event handler for each of the images
$imgs.on("click", function(){
  // Find the child elements within the output div that need updating and
  // extract the content from the array of objects that correspond
  // to the index of the image that was clicked.
  $(".title", $outputDiv).text(data[$(this).index()-1].title);
  $(".text", $outputDiv).text(data[$(this).index()-1].text);
});
});
```

```css
.section-link {
width: 50px;
height: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="section-link fairtrade" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
  <img class="section-link toxicfree" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
  <img class="section-link quality" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
  <img class="section-link organic" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
  <img class="section-link vegan" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">

  <div class="section-display active">
    <h2 class="title">Default Title</h2>
    <h2 class="text">Default Content</h2>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what your looking for, I've used animate to achive what i think you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Put all the images in a JavaScript array
  var $imgs = $(".section-link");

  // If you store your content in an array of objects, you can do this without creating
  // more than one display div. You'll just get the content from the object in the
  // array that has the same index as the image (within a different array)
  var data = [{
      title: "Fair trade",
      text: "The Process from start is fair to all who are included in making our clothes."
    },
    {
      title: "Toxicfree",
      text: "Our clothes does not contain any toxic materials and are made under toxicfree conditions."
    },
    {
      title: "Quality",
      text: "Our clothes have sustainable and high quality."
    },
    {
      title: "Organic",
      text: "All the materials and processes are fully organic and friendly to our planet."
    },
    {
      title: "Vegan",
      text: "We care about the animals, all clothes are crueltyfree and vegan."
    },
  ];

  // Get reference to the output area
  var $outputDiv = $(".section-display");
  var defaulttext = $outputDiv.find(".text").text()
  var defaultTitle = $outputDiv.find(".title").text();
  
  
  // Set a click event handler for each of the images
  $imgs.on("click", function() {
    // Find the child elements within the output div that need updating and
    // extract the content from the array of objects that correspond
    // to the index of the image that was clicked.
    $This = $(this)
    $(".title", $outputDiv).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, function() {
      $(".title", $outputDiv).text(data[$This.index() - 1].title)
        .animate({
          opacity: 1
        });
    });
    $(".text", $outputDiv).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, function() {
      $(".text", $outputDiv).text(data[$This.index() - 1].text)
        .animate({
          opacity: 1
        });
    })
  });

  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.section-display').length != 1 && $(e.target).closest(".section-link").length != 1) {
      $(".title", $outputDiv).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, function() {
        $(".title", $outputDiv).text(defaultTitle)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1
          });
      });
      $(".text", $outputDiv).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, function() {
        $(".text", $outputDiv).text(defaulttext)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1
          });
      })
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.section-link {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="section-link fairtrade" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
<img class="section-link toxicfree" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
<img class="section-link quality" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
<img class="section-link organic" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">
<img class="section-link vegan" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/e/e7/Big_GREEN_Button.png/revision/latest?cb=20110525071843" alt="">

<div class="section-display active">
  <h2 class="title">Default Title</h2>
  <h2 class="text">Default Content</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use jquery for animating, e.g.:

```
//optionally stop all currently running transitions:
$(".title .text").stop(true);
//first hide our text
$(".title .text").hide("slow",function(){
    //then if hidden, change
    $(".title", $outputDiv).text(data[$(this).index()-1].title);
    $(".text", $outputDiv).text(data[$(this).index()-1].text);
    //and show again
    $(".title .text").show("slow");
});
```